# When i try to call a function in my node.js electron app it throws an error. Function not defined at click event

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my **node.js** electron app, I got an error when I tried to call a function inside of my `bot.js`. I tried this:

```
<button type="button" class="startbutton" id="startbutton" onclick="init()">Start Bot</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require('./bot')
</script>
```

It always gives me the error [Screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6QZE.png)

```
function init() {
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('Pong!');
    }
});
client.login('<MyDiscordBotToken>')
}
```

Something is wrong, but I don't know what...

Comment: I dont see any `ipfpp` in your code example. Make [mcve], please

Comment: Oh yea i see, it is because i changed the function from ipfpp to init.